# convert List<Object> to System.Array[]

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have an `Array`

```
Array[] Values;
```

I sorted that `Array` using this code

```
List<Object> val= new List<Object>();

foreach (var arr in Values)
{
    if (arr.GetValue(1, 9).Equals("Impact"))
        val.Add(arr);
}
foreach (var arr in Values)
{
    if (arr.GetValue(1, 9).Equals("Critical"))
        val.Add(arr);
}
foreach (var arr in Values)
{
    if (arr.GetValue(1, 9).Equals("High"))
        val.Add(arr);
}
foreach (var arr in Values)
{
    if (arr.GetValue(1, 9).Equals("Medium"))
        val.Add(arr);
}
foreach (var arr in Values)
{
    if (arr.GetValue(1, 9).Equals("Low"))
        val.Add(arr);
}
```

now I have to convert the `List` val back to `System.Array[]`.

I have tried doing this using `Values = val.ToArray();` but it is giving compilation error that `object[]` cannot be converted to `System.Array[]` implicitly.

Is there any way to convert `List<object>` to `System.Array[]` explicitly ?

Or is there any other way to sort `Values`?

Comment: What is the data type of the `Array[]`?

Comment: What is the datatype of elements you are storing in Array[]?

Comment: Lets say the datatype it Class1 then you can declare your list List<Class1 > val= new List<Class1 >(); then list.toArray works.

Comment: There's really only very few valid use cases for `List<Object>` or untyped arrays - you might want to rethink this approach and do some more reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a little bit more `LINQ` `Select` will help you do the trick:

```
Array[] Values = val.Select(x => (Array)x).ToArray();
```

Note: every `x` must be convertible to `Array`.

That said, `Array` itself is already an array. `Array[]` seems to be `Array of Arrays` to me and the data types of the elements are not strongly typed.

```
Array a = new int[10]; //this is ok
Array b = new string[10]; //this is also ok
```

Thus, your `Array[]` may contain any strongly-typed arrays. `{int[], string[], double[]}` and so on...

Unless it is what you really want, it seems to be not so safe design - IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is a design issue. Why do you declare the val-List as an Object-List and not an Array-List in the first place?

So, why don't you use:

```
List<Object> val= new List<Array>();
```

instead of

```
List<Object> val = new List<Object>();
```

That way, an easy ToArray() call should work just fine.